# Программно выделить элемент в ListView по id

Tags: android

Добрый день. У меня `ListView` связан с адаптером где источник это таблица SQLite, мне нужно зная `id` строки выделить программно элемент `ListView`. Видел кучу примеров выделения по позиции но мне нужно выделить по `id` записи из SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом то деле задача сводится к тому, чтобы найти позицию в списке по `id` элемента списка и по найденной позиции применить: `ListView.setSelection(position)`

Есть 2 способа привязки id к position:

1) Врукопашную найти позицию списка по id, типа:

```
public int getPositionById(long id) {
    for (int position=0; position<mList.size(); position++)
        if (mList.get(position).getId() == id)
            return position;
    return 0;
}
```

способ откровенно херовый, особенно в случае когда бэкендом является `Cursor`

2) Способ 2 получше:

```
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     //blah-blah
     convertView.setTag(convertView.getId(),position); //позицию храним в теге
     return convertView;
}
```

Далее уже можно найти через тег:

```
int getItemPosition(View view) {
    return view.getTag(view.getId());
}
```

В случае `CursorAdapter` обычно вместо `getView()` используется пара `newView()/bindView()`, что сути не меняет - в исходниках `CursorAdapter()` написано примерно так:

```
/**
     * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getView(int, View, ViewGroup)
     */
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (!mDataValid) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("this should only be called when the cursor is valid");
        }
        if (!mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("couldn't move cursor to position " + position);
        }
        View v;
        if (convertView == null) {
            v = newView(mContext, mCursor, parent);
        } else {
            v = convertView;
        }
        bindView(v, mContext, mCursor);
        return v;
    }
```

Так что вставку тега можно смело вставлять в `bindView()`

Answer (score 1):

можно обойти весь курсор и сохранить в каком-нибудь `HashMap` соответствия id (ключ) и позиции курсора. А когда надо искать, тогда получить в этом `HashMap` по id позицию, ну и выделить его в `listView`